# ASP.NET is not fetching data from the database from local computer

Tags: asp.net, ssms

[web config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX2tC.png)

[SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbx5k.png)[Connection properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrXHI.png) [login pg showing invalid cred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQWsX.png)

I am new to ASP.NET and trying to make a login page and there is no compilation error but still, the login page is not fetching data from the database(SSMS here), and also I have attached the image. Logic is working fine and even the SQL query is running and still, the login page is showing invalid credentials. I have another fresh project still nothing happened. I'm stuck. Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Debug Log:
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\assembly\dl3\409aa399\001fe461_36f3d301\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\assembly\dl3\bd8a2022\00f4ddcc_14aece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\assembly\dl3\6e416322\20f92f9b_e194d601\First.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\assembly\dl3\801cca17\0048ca5e_2d6acd01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\assembly\dl3\49e687f5\00325974_6a96d501\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\assembly\dl3\e714a874\00d2e379_0f27cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\assembly\dl3\ad5ebe65\00d02783_e182ce01\WebGrease.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Design.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\App_Code.q9j-akl2.dll'.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Xaml.Hosting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'A_987284c3_d0ba_48b1_abe1_9927bfeec696'.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\Users\Preety\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\79b043ea\16e1d4b3\App_Web_zsfc5a2m.dll'.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132456938611030971): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x1b00 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4a7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5de8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3cd8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5dac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xbe8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3b50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x225c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8204] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

internal int Validate_user_login(string user, string pass)
{
string query = "SELECT * FROM[users].[dbo].[User_details] WHERE username=' " + user.ToString().Replace(" ' ", "''") + "' and password=' " + pass.ToString().Replace(" ' ", "''") + " ' ";
DataSet users = new DataSet();
int result = 0;

```
        try
        {
            users = GetDataSet(query);
            if (users != null)
            {
                if (users.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (users.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        result = users.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
```

}

Code is running fine but I don't know why its not fetching the results as SQL query as well as login credentials are correct.

Comment: I dont think it is a database error. Otherwise, you would get some kind of database related error or exception. If possible, try and put your login code in your question. I feel like you are new to asp.net. you should really spend some time on this - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/hello-world-tutorial/intro

Comment: What does GetDataSet do? Always use parameters in your SQL to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xQPgtSw0UT-CnlY6w5YnYa5xpv00l1vL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: U can go through this link, I have pasted my code here in a word file.